# Thai work visa cancelled, can i get a tourist visa before leaving?

Tags: thailand, visa-extensions, working-visas

If my Thai work visa gets cancelled by the employer, can I apply or get a tourist Thai visa while staying there in Thailand before leaving ?

Or is there any other way to renew my visa or stay there in Thailand?

Comment: While I am not familiar with Thai visa rules I can't image this happening, in general tourist visa is given if you can convince the authorities you do not want to live in the country which you have zero chance since you already do live there! I think the most you can get is a 7 day extension. But I am not sure so I am not posting this as an answer.

Comment: @chx - Extensions for visa holders and visa exemption entries is now 30 days, one time only, 1900 baht.  Tourists that enter under Visa on Arrival option get only 7 day extensions (unfortunately for the same price).

Answer (score 2):

You can not apply for a Tourist Visa inside Thailand, it has to be done at an Embassy or Consulate.  You can only extend a Tourist Visa within Thailand and that can only be done once for a cost that is about the same as applying for a new tourist visa.

I don't think your employer can cancel your 'visa'. They can get your work permit canceled, but in terms of your visa at best they can withdraw their intent to hire you and thus keep you from renewing your visa.

Depending on your citizenship, you can leave the country and perhaps come back in under the Visa Exemption program for 30 day stays.  But coupled with your recently expired visa for working, it may generate suspicion of trying to live in Thailand without the correct visa if you do this a couple of times in a row.  The government has been cracking down on expats who used the 30 day Visa Exemption to live in the country.

You can also visit a Thai Embassy in neighboring countries to apply for a tourist visa, which if you get one of the newer multiple entry one's gets you several 60 days entries.  But again your expired visa for working may be taken into consideration, as proof you intend to reside not just visit.

Comment: I think but not sure if op was already on an extension then yes unemployment means loss of visa too.

Comment: If the OP is on his original one year B visa and gets laid off, the visa is still valid.  If he has been working more than one year and has used the extension service, then yes his extension becomes invalid.  But if he gets a new job prior to the old work permit expiring he can maintain his extension with the new work permit.  In either case, the "visa" does not get cancelled by the employer, as in the second case the visa has already expired but the OP has been given permission to remain in the country..